# Opening files located in Java jar directory, not Current Working Directory

Tags: java, relative-path

I have a **Java desktop application** that I developed in NetBeans which I zip up to distribute to students.  Inside this zip file I have the **.jar**, a "lib" directory that contains the swing-layout jar, and a directory I named "sourcefiles" that contains all the text files needed for the program.

All works fine if the jar file is double clicked, but when run from the **command line** (`java -jar MyApp.jar`), it **can only find the "sourcefiles" directory** if you first cd to the directory that the file is in before running the command, something that the some students forget to do.  Apparently there is no way to change the current working directory from within my code.  The path to "sourcefiles" is given in my code as a **relative path**, assuming that I am in the **MyApp** folder.   So what can I do so that the program can be run from the command line without having to **cd** to the containing directory?  Is there something to add this to the manifest file?

This problem is faced mostly by students using Linux, but it is the same on Mac.  I assume it's the same on Windows, but I guess none of the students with Windows run it from the command line.

Comment: How do you access your resources in your code ?

Comment: BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8") );                           where filename is a relative path: sourcefiles/xxxxx.             The jar file to run the program, a java library, and the sourcefiles folder are all in a folder which I then zip up to send to students.  I didn't want to have the sourcefiles included in the jar, since they are resources that may be modified by the program.  This path has seemed to work for everything except from the command line. (These are humanities students, some more tech-savvy than others.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default directory, but you can get the directory the Jar the class is running in and use that in your code as the base path.

```
String jarLocation = ThisClass.class.getProtectionDomain()
                         .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

From this you can get the directory the jar is in. Most likely you will want to wrap this up as a method your students can call.

Comment: I used  zikaDirectory = jarFile.getParentFile().getName();  and then  if (!zikaDirectory.equals(currentWorkingDirName))  to find out if this was happening, but I am puzzled about the last line of your post about a method the students using the program can call.

Comment: @Numa I suggest you give students some code which hides some of the more difficult code.